# How does Windows hide internal users?

Tags: windows, hacking, user-accounts

I just recognized that Windows hides some special users, like for example the `NT Authority\SYSTEM` user or the users which are added after the installation of SQL Server (`ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS`, `IIS_IURS`, ...). I know that it is possible to execute applications under the privileges from a specific user, so it works fine. From my understanding, the users are active, but not accessible from while try to login when the computer starts. Windows also displays only specific users, so there must be a option in Windows where it is possible to define whether a user account should be visible or not.

Just for my interests, I tried to make the hidden user accounts visible. After few minutes of some research, I stumbled upon a registry hack: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList`. For some reason, it won't work on my machine. I also tried to reboot my computer and stuff like that.

But someshow Windows must have an option where to hide the useres. Where is it? I search for few hours and checked all the options available Windows - I was not able to find a way. My goal is to make it possible to login in as `NT Authority\SYSTEM` from the welcome screen. How do I do that and where has windows protected this possibility? Why does not `net users` display the other users (except mine, guest, administrator)?

Comment: Dig into TechNet... there is probably a reason this is sandboxed from you.

Comment: The reg key you're referring to is for hiding user accounts from the old Windows XP non-domain logon screen that presents a list of local users of the system. Presumably the same key works for Vista/7 also.

Comment: SYSTEM is not a user account.  There is no way to log into it from the welcome screen.

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to make it possible to login in as NT Authority\SYSTEM from the welcome screen. How do I do that and where has windows protected this possibility?

You won't be able to do this.  The account is not an interactive account.  See here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: run "cmd" via the "at" command it will open up a cmd with system privs.

Comment: @tony yeah I know about the "hack" but that's not what he's asking to do.  The hack requires admin privileges so you might as well just use an admin account.  The "hack" is more of a trick that is pretty pointless.

Comment: yep in this case its pointless.